# Requiring a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm trying to require a class in javascript (using node if you want to know) and at the moment its not erroring on the require but not really requiring right, heres the class code

```
class npc {
    constructor(name, dialog) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dialog = dialog;

    }

    rdialog() {
        this.tts = dialog[Math.floor(Math.random()*dialog.lensgth)];
        return this.tts;
    }
}
```

and here's the way I'm trying to require it
var `npc = require('../Npcs/npc.js');` i keep getting a empty object {} cant seem to find a answer when i get somewhat further i end up with a function named npc

Comment: You're not exporting your class.

Comment: did you misspell this `lensgth` I think it should be `length`, right ?

Comment: both of those are right but i still dont get what i need when i export it when i do `export default class` i get an error " unexpected token export"

Comment: when i export it doing `module.exports = class npc` i can console.log it and itll show my class code but when i do npc.rdialog() i get an error saying it isnt a function

Comment: @KingCosmic It should be `new npc().rdialog()`